# How to implment a SNTP request via LWIP netconn interface?

Tags: lwip

I have a question.

lwip-contrib STABLE-1_4_1 provide the sntp.c and sntp.h using raw API, but my project have already chosen sequential API via netconn. Is there a sample code using netconn to retrieve network time (NTP)? Thanks in advance!

Kevin

Comment: Mention code you've tried with issues faced here at Stack.